# Node waiting for sqlite to return results

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I'm fairly new to Node from Python so I'm used to my code executing in the order in which I write it and this has got me a little stumped.

I'm basically getting rows back from my SQLite database and performing an operation on each row then keeping a running total. I then want the final total to reply back to the user (This is a Discord bot)

I've attempted to wrap my code inside a Promise but not when it runs my bot crashes saying 'query is not defined'

```
async function feelingCommand(username,receivedMessage){
let sqlStatement = `SELECT Message FROM discord WHERE User = ? ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 2`;
let total = 0;
const query = await new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    db.run(sqlStatement, (err) => {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err.message);
        reject(err); 
    }
    db.each(sqlStatement, [username], (err, row) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
        let score = sentiment.analyze(`${row.Message}`).comparative;
        total = total + score;

      });
      resolve(query);
});
});
console.log(total)
```

}

I'd be very grateful for any help in pointing me in the right direction. To be honest, I'm surprised I got this far :)

Comment: From what I see, you don't need the `db.run` call at all. `db.each` will run the query with the `username` parameter and perform the addition on `total`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well my addition searching indicated that db.each is a pain to promisify so I switched to using db.all and a foreach loop with a promise

```
async function feelingCommand(username,receivedMessage){
let sqlStatement = `SELECT Message FROM discord WHERE User = ? ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 2`;
let total = 0;
const query = await new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    db.all(sqlStatement, [username], (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
        rows.forEach((row) => {
            console.log(row.name);
            let score = sentiment.analyze(`${row.Message}`).comparative;
            total = total + score;
      });
      resolve(total);
    });
})
```